# Collapsed navbar drop down color

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, colors, navbar

I am using bootstrap navbar-fixed-top and have set to always be collapsed.

I would like the color of the drop down to be a different colour to that of the main navbar, a bit like the nag on this site: http://wearehanno.com/

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

```
 <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>/"><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></a>
    </div>

    <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse" role="navigation">
      <?php
        if (has_nav_menu('primary_navigation')) :
          wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'primary_navigation', 'menu_class' => 'nav navbar-nav'));
        endif;
      ?>
    </nav>
  </div>

.navbar-brand {
  display: block;
  background: url(../img/logo.svg) no-repeat;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  height: 54px;
  width:216px;
  margin-top:10px;
  background-position:center; 
}

.navbar-collapse { background:#333333; }

@grid-float-breakpoint:     9999px;
```

Answer (score 4):

Add the following rule to your CSS.

```
.navbar-collapse { background:#cccccc; /*replace with desired color*/ }
```

To make the background full-width on larger screens, add:

```
@media(min-width: 768px){
    .navbar > .container { max-width: 100%; padding: 0; }
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bc32m/3)**

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for your speedy response...is there a way to get the background color to go full width?

Comment: It appears full width to me. Are you talking about the demo or in your code? Could you share your markup and relevant CSS in the original question?

Comment: I've added the code - the demo is full width until the navbar is no longer collapsed, I have set ,mine so it is always collapsed by setting grid-float-breakpoint:999px so the drop down is not showing full width on larger screen.

Comment: @Ben I have updated my answer to include the full width CSS. Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help, but with this code it makes the navbar 100% wide. Really I only want the drop down to be 100% wide, is that possible?

Comment: You can set your desired width on .navbar to control the width of the entire navbar.

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact opposite problem and need my navigation to move the target up where it normally would be. Anybody ready to take on a tougher fragment identifier navbar challenge please see stackoverflow: http://bit.ly/1avVcwf

While I was trying to solve my problem I started using divs to move the results of targets up and down the page as divs are block elements by default and I wrote the div immediately before the intended fragment identifier target like this:

```css
.bottom-margin-spacer{
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class=bottom-margin-spacer>&nbsp;</div>
<div id="fragment-identifier-target-1>lorum ipsum</div>
<div class=bottom-margin-spacer>&nbsp;</div>
<div id="fragment-identifier-target-2>lorum ipsum</div>
```

As I recall I was successful to keep targets "pushed" down but I am still not successful to have the targets positioned at the top of the page. So I only mention my own problem because I learned how to solve the question being asked by Brandon and offer my solution as one of several which can reposition the target downwards.

As for the question about how to extend the dropdown menu of a navbar that is answered here at stackoverflow. I saw it yesterday and so can anybody else by learning to use search using [bootstrap] tag and string literals like "navbar" and "dropdown menu"

If you think this is a good answer please mark as an answer